# QML ListView with header and currentIndex position

Tags: qt, user-interface, listview, qml

Qt  6.3.2
ListView is used with header and headerPositioning = ListView.OverlayHeader. When current index is set and selection animation occurs, selected item is under header

There my code

**Аctual behavior**
When clicking on the item, it moving under header, why? If set `preferredHighlightBegin` and  `preferredHighlightEnd` then there will be a large indent between the header and the first item.

**Expected Behavior**
When clicking on  the item, it moving to position after header

```
ListView {
    id: journalView
    Layout.fillHeight: true
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    clip: true
    flickableDirection: Flickable.HorizontalAndVerticalFlick

    boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
    snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem

    //preferredHighlightBegin: 60
    //preferredHighlightEnd: 120
    highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
    highlightMoveDuration: 500
    highlightMoveVelocity: -1

    currentIndex: 0
    property int selectedIndex: -1
    model: _root.model

    headerPositioning: ListView.OverlayHeader
    header: ItemDelegate {

        z: 2
        implicitHeight: 60
        implicitWidth: 200

        background: Rectangle {
            border.color: Material.frameColor
            color: "#BDBDBD"
        }
        
        text: "Header"
    }

    delegate: ItemDelegate {

        property int row: index

        implicitHeight: 60
        implicitWidth: 200
        highlighted: row === journalView.selectedIndex

        background: Rectangle {
            color: {
                if (highlighted) {
                    return Material.color(Material.LightBlue, Material.Shade100)
                }
                return "transparent"
            }
            border.color: Material.frameColor
        }

        onClicked: {
            journalView.selectedIndex = row
            journalView.currentIndex = row
        }

        text: display
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Still not perfect, but very close. Use this settings:

```
    preferredHighlightBegin: 60
    preferredHighlightEnd: 60

    highlightRangeMode: selectedIndex >= 0 ? ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange :
                                            ListView.ApplyRange
```

The only thing not working here is, that you can scroll to the top after selecting an item and then the gap is there. But I think, you should be able to handle this somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the behavior is still far from ideal. An empty line appears between the header and the data. (don't ask me why I use ListView and not TableView, that's how it should be :) )
https://imgur.com/jVCj94T

Right now I'm just using ListView.ApplyRange, it looks like StrictlyEnforceRange doesn't work correctly if a header is used.